# What word describes a person who signs an official document?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, legalese

For example, I have a document that has the signatures of three people, all public servants: a tax collector,an inspector, and a school principal. How could I collectively describe these three people?

This entry offers [signatory](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24283/your-signature-vs-your-mark) but it implies a party to a contract.

Comment: I suppose it depends on *why* they are signing. If they're not a party of the agreement/contract of the document, they might be a "witness".

Comment: I think *signatory* doesn't necessarily apply just to contracts. There is the obscure word *attestant*, which means a person who attests to the genuineness of a document or signature by adding his or her own signature http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=attestant&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=00

Comment: The terminology may largely depend on the place and the nature of the document.   

It is rare that one document is actually signed by three public   service officers from diffrent branches of government. It is more likely that one is the Issuer of the (?certificate) document and the others are Attestors.

Comment: In your case, 'signatory' is not appropriate.

Comment: The reason for signing does matter. I could imagine the scenario you describe involving each signing their own certification of compliance with a list of requirements. In this case "certifier" might be more appropriate and "signer" might be more generic if the reason for signing isn't relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Props to @JLG for making me look this up.) *Signatory* need not refer simply to a party in a contract. While some dictionaries define it that way:

> NOAD: a party that has signed an agreement, esp. a country that has signed a treaty
>
> Collins English Dictionary (via Dictionary.com): person who has signed a document such as a treaty or contract or an organization, state, etc, on whose behalf such a document has been signed
>
> Cambridge Dictionaries Online: a person, organization or country which has signed an agreement
>
> Oxford Dictionaries Online: a party that has signed an agreement, especially a state that has signed a treaty: *Britain is a signatory to the convention*

Others define it more broadly.

> M-W: a signer with another or others *signatories to a petition*; especially : a government bound with others by a signed convention
>
> Random House Dictionary (via Dictionary.com): a signer, or one of the signers, of a document: *France and Holland were among the signatories of the treaty.*
>
> Wikipedia: The writer of a signature is a **signatory.**

Notice, however, that these last three seem to be more layman's dictionaries than comprehensive ones. In light of this, **it would seem that it is all right to use *signatory* in informal or non-official usage, but that a better word might be needed for official use.**

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Why not **signers**, as in the [*signers* of the Declaration of Independence](http://www.ushistory.org/declaration/signers/index.htm)?

Answer (score 4):

Many dictionaries suggest the use of *signee*.

> NOAD and Oxford Dictionaries Online: a person who has signed a contract or other official document.
>
> M-W (sign): a : to affix a signature to : ratify or attest by hand or seal *sign a bill into law, sign a confession* b : to assign or convey formally *signed over his property to his brother* c : to write down (one's name) d : to affix one's name to *a signed review*
>
> Dictionary.com (quoting the Random House Dictionary): a person who signs  a document, register, etc.; signer; signatory: *a signee of the declaration of independence*.

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.</sub>

Comment: You buried the [lede](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lede): The answer is [signatory](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/signatory)

Comment: @Robusto, I don't get it. However, JLG's comment made me go and look up *signatory*; see my other answer.

Comment: Generally, an -er is the person who does something, and the -ee is the person who receives the action (Payer, payee; lessor, lessee). How is *signee* someone who signs?

Comment: The online OED also gives for 'signee': 'A person who has signed a contract, petition, register, etc'

Comment: @AndrewLeach, -ee in NOAD: "2 denoting a person described as or concerned with : *absentee | patentee*"; in Random House (@Dictionary.com): "recent formations now also mark the performer of an act, with the base being an intransitive verb (*escapee; returnee; standee*) or, less frequently, a transitive verb (*attendee*) or another part of speech (*absentee; refugee*)."

Comment: "signee" is very rarely used. "signer" would be a better word.

Answer (score 0):

**Notary** is possibly what you seek. From Chambers,

> Notary - An official authorized to certify deeds, contracts, copies of documents, affidavits, etc (generally notary public)

**EDIT**: If you are in India, you are possibly referring to [a gazetted officer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazetted_Officer_%28India%29). I do not know if the same term is used elsewhere. Wiki does not say so.

Comment: No, a notary is a specific occupation, with required training and certification and licensing. Notice the word "authorized" in the definition. Neither a tax collector, an inspector, or a school principal are likely to also be notaries.

Comment: @Marthaª: Thanks, I think the answer should be a *gazetted officer*.

Comment: I've never heard the term *gazetted officer*. If I had to guess at a meaning, I'd think something military. I would not in a million years come up with "someone who signed a document". And looking at the page you linked, it looks like this is an Indian version of *notary*, so still very much not the meaning the OP is after.

Comment: @Martha Any of these people MIGHT be a notary, but this would be irrelevant to the fact that they signed the document. :-)

Comment: -1. A 'Gazetted officer' is one  authorized to attest douments,  similar to a 'Notary': not the one who has  originally signed (and issued) the document.   
   
The terms may not be relevent everywhere (outside India).

Comment: In the US, a "notary" is, as Martha says,  a specific occupation. But more specifically, it's someone who is authorized by the government to certify that a signature on a document is authentic. A notary is not a signer in the sense the OP means, but rather someone who certifies that the signer is really who he claims to be.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you're describing, a term like "authorized person", "official", "appropriate official", etc might be what you're looking for.