# One word to describe "someone who made a pact"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the one-word equivalent to the german word "Paktierer".

> "to do a deal with so."

In relation to making a deal with the devil / making a deal with a demon (or perhaps other similar entities). It would translate to: "A person who made a deal with the devil / a demon."

We use the term frequently while playing DSA (The Dark Eye, german RPG) and I always wondered about a good english equivalent. The word should be usable to describe a person: "Bob is a X".

Comment: This could well be a lexical gap.

Comment: Searchning for `one who signs a pact OR contract` revealed https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65037/what-word-describes-a-person-who-signs-an-official-document . Could it be applicable?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/devil_dealer

Comment: Google suggests pact-maker or deal-maker. A "party" is someone who enters into a deal, but I guess the word has too many other meanings to be useful in many contexts (such as in MMORPGs.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite the right fit, but a **warlock** is a practitioner of magic who gains their power from a pact with the devil.

Answer (score 2):

Since his name is arguably mostly associated with the pact he made with the devil, maybe '**Faust**', 'Faustus', or uncapitalized 'faust', can serve as an obvious synonym for *a person who made a deal with the devil*, e.g. 'Bob is a faust'.